# install python 2.6.6 in debian 8

Tags: debian, python-2.6

I need to install python 2.6.6 or 2.6.7 in Debian 8.2.
I am a user.
I tried to install but I have a error message:
"Failed to found the necessary bits to build the modules......."

I want to do this course:
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-01sc-introduction-to-electrical-engineering-and-computer-science-i-spring-2011/

I have python 2.7.9 at this moment.
When I run a  file(.py) in the shell of Idle  I have a error message:

ImportError: Bad magic number in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lib601/sm.pyc

I think this error is because I have the wrong python version.

Comment: maybe you need to find a more recent version of the course - it's 5 years old...

Comment: I tried but  I can not found a course more recent in the MIT  WEB

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working with the newest Debian Ubuntu build, which *should* work identically to your system.  While on Windows, one would simply be able to un-install Python, and re-install the respective version, Linux doesn't really work like that.  Since Linux is highly dependant on Python, un-intalling it wouldn't be beneficial to your system in any way, and may possibly mess things up a bit.  Linux, however, definitely allows for multiple versions of Python.

Since Python 2.6.x is highly unsupported now-a-days, it is rather hard to install.  You'll want to install this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes), which allows the installation of multiple Python builds.  You can do it by using the terminal and typing `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes`.  After that, run the update: `sudo apt-get update`, and then choose your version of Python: `sudo apt-get install python2.6 python2.6-dev`, possibly substituting for other versions.

The 'magic number' error is almost definitely from running an older python file on a newer version -- or perhaps you edited a .pyc file on accident.  Regardless, I would, due to preference, not even bother with Idle, and just use the built in terminal, launching python files as so: `python test.py`.

Now, if you want to run a Python file through a specific version of python, use: `pythonx.x test.py`, 'x.x' being the version number.

Hoped this answer helped!